# Why does my Samsung A8 have such poor contrast after updating to Android 9?

Tags: samsung

I have a Samsung A8 2018 SM-A530W, which was purchased from a major Canadian carrier. It recently updated itself to Android 9 through a Samsung application.

Since that update, many of my applications are very difficult to read. In the case of Calendar and Clock, the contrast ratio between the text and background makes text illegible. In the case of the settings screen, transparency to the wallpaper does the same. I'm sure this isn't intentional, but I'm wondering what I can do besides reset my phone.

[image: White text on an almost-white background.]

White text on an almost-white background makes the calendar impossible to read.

[image: Gray text over a gray background makes the clock difficult to read.]

Gray text over a gray background makes the clock difficult to read.

[image: Black text over a transparent background to the default Galaxy wallpaper makes settings difficult to read.]

Black text over a transparent background to the default Galaxy wallpaper makes settings difficult to read.

Comment: Check if there is the possibility to activate a dark mode. This should increase the contrast between backgrund and text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change that.

1. Go to Settings -> Accessibility -> Visibilty enhancements -> then try some functions there and see what is best for you (contrast theme,contrast font etc.)
2. If you are using any Galaxy Theme, after system update, they are also updated, so this can alse be a problen. You should try to change or just dissable theme you are using(if you are using) for a moment to test it.
3. If you love Night Mode,it can also solve your problem, but it is not good for using outside.

Comment: Visibility Enhancements aren't the right fix here. These are pretty invasive options for people with severe visual impairements. None of them look proper for a regularly sighted person. However changing the Galaxy Theme from the default I was given to one actually named "default" fixed the majority of the issues. Marking this as solved.